# What do we do now that stackoverflow.com has usurped the term "stack overflow"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, seo, search-engine

I'm actually trying to google some information on real, honest-to-goodness stack overflow error that is happening deep inside an app, and all I'm getting is unrelated topics from stackoverflow.com or that mention stackoverflow.com.  We need a new code word to stay one step ahead of the game.

Comment: It's a pretty trivial problem to understand though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow Only finding and fixing it in the real code may be a bit tougher, but Google ain't ever going to help in this. Just post a question along with the code and the trace :)

Comment: Please give us the search you are using so we can better help you.  If not, try using "stack bounds" and similar terms, which are more technically correct anyway.  Also, the exact error message you are receiving, if there is one, should give you very precise search results.

Comment: Ask a question on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try using `-site:stackoverflow.com -"stackoverflow.com"` in your google search :)

Comment: That works partially, but I get a lot of hits from other forms that contain so.com Urls

Comment: The problem is that the best answers might be on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Updated answer to even include references to "stackoverflow.com" :)

Comment: That actually helps quite a bit with both operators involved.  Thank you for not submitting a self-referential answer.

Comment: @user152304 glad could be of help. Though hope you got a flavor of why google search is so 'stackoverflow'ed ;).

Answer (score 12):

Try asking a question on Stack Overflow.  That is what it's there for.

Comment: It's here to nullify the usability of general search engines?

Comment: @user152304: No, that's what *you* said, not me.  *I* said that you should try *asking a question*.

Comment: Yes, rather than using a general purpose search engine, which has been rendered useless.

Comment: @user152304: If you can't use Google because Web sites have names, I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: @user152304 I think the point Bill is getting at, is that SO was *built for this*.  StackOverflow **wants to be the top Google result for all programming concerns**.  A *stack overflow error* is no different.  It could be argued you will get *worse* help/results if you exclude SO.com from your search.

Comment: @bill  Feel free to stop trying.

Comment: At first I thought this was an always-friday-in-iceland kind of question, but I think OP is actually complete serious...

Comment: It actually wasn't serious, I was just enjoying the snark-nerd replies, however the manipulations of Google operators to avoid this problem were appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Doing a google search for "stack overflow error" actually only returns 1 so.com reference: http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=stack+overflow+error. Perhaps your search itself is flawed. What language and platform are you working on and what is the specific stack overflow error you are getting?

Comment: The search was more complex than "stack overflow error", involving iis and some bits from a minidump.  I'll see if I can find one exactly, but I was getting lots of hits from so.com about iis, and many from msdn about stackoverflow.com.  I think the -operator above is the way to go in google, at least.

Comment: But you still haven't come out and stated what your problem is beyond not liking the fact that so.com is coming up in searches. What are you trying to find?

Answer (score 6):

if you just search for `stack overflow`, youll probably get only references to the site. I just searched for

> stack overflow java

and

> stack overflow c++

and both queries turned up plenty of legitimate discussions on the issue. Sounds like your queries can use some refinement.

Answer (score 5):

Try some of the following search tips:

- Replace the weak search term with a characteristic identifier, e.g. "StackOverflowException"
- Use an entire phrase from an error message, e.g. "stack overflow in line 0"
- Combine the weak search terms with refining search term, e.g. "stack overflow" "internet explorer"