# The stack overflow quandary: How do I research an actual stack overflow exception?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, seo, search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do we do now that stackoverflow.com has usurped the term “stack overflow”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91160/what-do-we-do-now-that-stackoverflow-com-has-usurped-the-term-stack-overflow)

I just discovered the dark side of Stack Overflow, with it being one of the more popular sites on the Internet: trying to troubleshoot an actual stack overflow exception using the Internet or the Stack Overflow website.

Does anybody have suggestions about to leave out the brand name and target solutions, to help this frustrated user with an actual stack overflow.

Comment: There's a lot of irony in that this exact question (the Stack Overflow website interfering in Googling for the actual exception) has been asked on Meta, but I am running into some... issues... searching for it. Whilst I search, though, consider adding `-site:stackoverflow.com` into your Google search query.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you can search using the [stack-overflow] tag as a filter.  There are a couple of mis-uses of the tag, but for the most part, the tag actually represents stack overflows.

Comment: Ah, found it - [here's the duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91160/what-do-we-do-now-that-stackoverflow-com-has-usurped-the-term-stack-overflow). I suggest reviewing the answers there, they give some tips on what to do.